# Best way to check if one of other objects is true or not

Tags: c++, function

I am looking for best way to implement this scenario:

I have 4 objects that have Boolean member that in the flow of the app sometimes they are set to true and sometimes are set to false depending on conditions;

Then I have final function that gets 1 of this objects and needs to check if in the other 3 objects one of them has the member set to true .

The problem is I know how to do the dirty check , and I am searching for cleaner way here is my code for the final function:

```
class Obj
{
public :
   Obj(int _id) : id(_id)
   bool status;
   int id // only 4 objects are created 0,1,2,3
}

m_obj0 = new Obj(0) ;
m_obj1 = new Obj(1) ;
m_obj2 = new Obj(2) ;
m_obj3 = new Obj(3) ;

bool check(Obj* obj)
{
   if(obj->id == 0)
   {
      if(m_obj1->status || m_obj2->status || m_obj3->status)
      {
          return true;
      }
      return false;
   }else if(obj->id == 1)(
      if(m_obj0->status || m_obj2->status || m_obj3->status)
      {
          return true;
      }
      return false;
   }else if(obj->id == 2)(
      if(m_obj0->status || m_obj1->status || m_obj3->status)
      {
          return true;
      }
      return false;
   }else if(obj->id == 3)(
      if(m_obj0->status || m_obj1->status || m_obj2->status)
      {
          return true;
      }
      return false;

}
```

is there a shorter and cleaner way to accomplish this  check function ?

Comment: Would be nice if you mentioned which programming language this is.

Comment: i did it in some c++ but it really doesn't  matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set m_obj as an array. Then use a for loop to check

```
bool check(Obj* obj)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
        if (obj->id == i) continue;
        if (m_obj[i]->status == true)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or add them together, then subtract m_obj[obj->id]->status。Check the result is zero or not

```
bool check(Obj* obj)
{
    int result = m_obj[0]->status+m_obj[1]->statusm_obj[2]->status
                +m_obj[3]->status-m_obj[obj->id]->status;
    return (result!=0);
}
```

Comment: its also option , by the way i need only one of them to be true 
so you can add break; after the first find. 
but i wander if there is better way .. thanks!

Comment: @user63898 The function will return true after the first find, you don't need a break after return.

Comment: what is more Effective if i know i have only 4 objects 
to check them as i did of do the loop check ?

Comment: @user63898 Do you like the new one?